# Command line MSBuild fails to compile code

Tags: c#, command-line, compilation, compiler-errors, msbuild

Can anyone tell me why command-line msbuild fails to build this code?

```
public SourceControlHandler(string sourceControlUser = null, string sourceControlPassword = null, string sourceControlDomain = null)
        {    
            var client = new SvnClient();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceControlUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceControlPassword))
            {
                client.Authentication.Clear();
                client.Authenticatio​n.UserNameHandlers += delegate (object sender, Sv​nUserNameEventArgs e)
                {
                    e.UserName = SourceControlUser;
                };
            _svnClient = client;
        }
```

The errors are:

```
d:\DEV\EP.BuildAndDeploy\BuildResources\BuildProjects.build" (Rebuild target)
1) ->
D:\DEV\EP.BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj" (default targ
t) (5) ->
CoreCompile target) ->
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,39): error CS1002: ; expected [D:\DEV\EP.
uildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,39): error CS1525: Invalid expression ter
 '.' [D:\DEV\EP.BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,40): error CS1002: ; expected [D:\DEV\EP.
uildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,107): error CS1026: ) expected [D:\DEV\EP
BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,108): error CS1002: ; expected [D:\DEV\EP
BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,108): error CS1525: Invalid expression te
m ')' [D:\DEV\EP.BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(44,109): error CS1002: ; expected [D:\DEV\EP
BuildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(48,14): error CS1002: ; expected [D:\DEV\EP.
uildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
 Handlers\SourceControlHandler.cs(50,10): error CS1513: } expected [D:\DEV\EP.
uildAndDeploy\EP.BuildService\EP.BuildService.csproj]
```

Visual Studio 2015 has no issues compiling it and the code is not throwing any run-time errors. 
The listed code starts at line 38. Therefore MSBuild/CSC is complaining - first error - about the second dot in: client.Authenticatio​n.UserNameHandlers;

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a not displayable character in `Authentication` between `o`and `n`.
You can see it when playing with arrow keys on keyboard.

Comment: My friend, I owe you a beer! :) I've been running in circles for hours.
To confirm your solution, I've deleted and rewritten the code. It seems to be working now!