# Building solution in MS Build throws (Non-Displayable Char?) Error

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Building solution in MS Build fails with error(given the sample error below). But when i try to build the same solution in VS, the build succeeds. Once built in VS, if i try in MSBuild, then it works.

I came across [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048043/command-line-msbuild-fails-to-compile-code) where i found that non-displyable character may be the issue. So i commented '=>' characters and try building it again, it succeeded.

Error Thrown:

```
App\AllActions.cs(27,43): error CS1002: ; expected[D:\DEM1\AAA\framework\Core\Core.csproj] 
App\AllActions.cs(27,50): error CS1520: Method must have a return type [D:\DEM1\AAA\framework\Core\Core.csproj]
```

My Code is,

```
    public Alert Alert => new Alert();
    public Button Button => new Button();
    public Checkbox Checkbox => new Checkbox();
    public Dropdown Dropdown => new Dropdown();
    public Frame Frame => new Frame();
    public Label Lable => new Label();
    public Link Link => new Link();`
```

- MSBuild version = C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin
- Visual Studio 2017
- c# Version = 7.0

Any help on how to sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using a version of *msbuild* (MSBuild 12.0) that doesn't support *expression bodied properties* added in C# 7.0.

The *msbuild* version you are using is seemingly from 2015 which AFAIK doesn't support C# 7.0

Try a later version of *msbuild*

Comment: Thanks. It worked with C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin